# Linq query in custom class

Tags: c#, linq, class

Have a custom class named `Company` and I'm looking to get a single instance of this class returned based on a single `Company.AccountID` that I'm passing. I have most of the query, but I'm messing it up somewhere. Can someone help me out here?

`Company cmp = Companies.Select(comp => comp.AccountID == accountID).Select(comp => new Company());`

Comment: you should remove the `class` tag, it doesn't really.. suit the question

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like:

```
Company obj = Companies.FirstOrDefault(comp=> comp.AccountID == accountID);
```

In your current query you are selecting result of a boolean operation. What you need is `Where` like:

```
Companies.Where(comp => comp.AccountID == accountID)
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<Company>` object matching your condition, later you can add `FirstOrDefault /First` at the end of your query like:

```
Company c = Companies.Where(comp => comp.AccountID == accountID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Remember `FirstOrDefault` will return null, if no matching record is found. `First` on the other hand will throw an exception.

To select a single record from a collection, your options are [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb291976%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) / [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.single%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) / [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) , [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549138%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) / [LastOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb301849%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). *(Last/LastOrDefault is only supported through LINQ to objects, it is not supported with Entity framework)*

Comment: You may combine Where and First / FirstOrDefault: 
   First(x=>x.AccountID == accountID)

Answer (score 3):

You have several options, you'll have to chose the best fit for you.

1. Use `First` if you expect several matches based on your LINQ query but want an Exception thrown if there isn't at least one:

   ```
   var company = Companies.First(c => c.AccountID == accountID);
   ```
2. Use `FirstOrDefault` if you expect several matches based on your LINQ query and want `null` if there are no matches.

   ```
   var company = Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AccountID == accountID);
   ```
3. Use `Single` if your query should return exactly one record. If there is any other result, an exception will be thrown.

   ```
   var company = Companies.Single(c => c.AccountID == accountID);
   ```
4. Use `SingleOrDefault` if your query should return 0 or 1 record. If no record is found, `null` will be returned.

   ```
   var company = Companies.SingleOrDefault(c => c.AccountID == accountID);
   ```

Just be sure to make the right choice. Being specific with your choice of method now will express your intent to other developers in the future so that bugs don't slowly introduce themselves because of a query that was too generic.